# ASP.net HTTP Post when auto-incrementing row Id

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I am working in ASP.net with a Web API allowing HTTP Posts to update a mapped SQL database.

I want the Id to be automatically increment by one every time a new row is inserted. The table definition is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PoolTests] (
[Id]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1),
[SiteID] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Date]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Tub]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[par1]   FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[par2]   FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[par3]   FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[par4]   FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL
);
```

I have mapped the table to a class as such:

```
    public class PoolTest
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string SiteID { get; set; }
       public string Date { get; set; }
       public string Tub { get; set; }
       public double par1 { get; set; }
       public double par2 { get; set; }
       public double par3 { get; set; }
       public double par4 { get; set; }
    }
```

I am adding the data to the database via a `HTTP Post Request`:

```
        // POST: api/PoolTests
        [ResponseType(typeof(PoolTest))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostPoolTest([FromBody]PoolTest poolTest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.PoolTests.Add(poolTest);
            db.SaveChanges();

           return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = poolTest.Id }, poolTest);
        }
```

The problem is if I send my request containing the `Id` i.e.:

```
{"Id": 1, "SiteID": "sample string 2", "Date": "sample string 3", "Tub": "sample string 5", "par1": 5.1, "par2": 6.1, "par3": 7.1, "par4": 8}
```

Then I get this exception:

**"The model backing the 'WebApplicationMVCContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database**

at the line `db.PoolTests.Add(poolTest);`

Or if I omit to send the `Id`:

```
{ "SiteID": "sample string 2", "Date": "sample string 3", "Tub": "sample string 5", "par1": 5.1, "par2": 6.1, "par3": 7.1, "par4": 8}
```

because it is an auto incrementing field then I don't receieve a VS exception, but fiddler reports a

> 400   HTTP    localhost:53660 /api/PoolTests  149 no-cache; Expires: -1   application/json; charset=utf-8 fiddler:6644

So I am not sure whether the problem is coming from the way I have configured the table with the auto-incrementing row Id, the mapping of the model class to the database of the HTTP request?

Comment: When you get http 400, does your table get updated properly? If yes, do you have a GET method in PoolTests controller?

Comment: No the table does not get updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exception means your model classes do not match with the database tables exactly.

If you are in a database-first scenario (you design the database and then you make the classes) then you should add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to your project and select the Code First from Database option.

This will generate all classes automatically to your project, based on your database structure.

To do that, please look at this guide that explains step by step how to make it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

Comment: Also note that your class in the example does not match the SQL table being created. The SQL one has constraints applied to it, like SiteID's max length: Your class has no Data Annotations explicitly telling Entity Framework it has a max length of 128. In this case it will default to max length of MAX. Same goes for the other types.

Comment: I took the advice here and rebuilt the project using an Entity Framework approach and allowed that to build the model using a database first approach. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.